# Getting Client IP Address with proxy - PHP5.4.4-14 + APACHE 2.2.22-13 + Debian 7 + HTTPS

Tags: php, apache2.2

I tried every codes and read all posts with this topic, but none resolved my problem.

The code doesnt get the real IP when the browser option "use proxy for intranet sites" is on.
It shows me the PROXY IP...

Code:

```
function get_ip_address()
{
    $aa = array ( 'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 'HTTP_FORWARDED', // 'HTTP_HOST', 'REMOTE_ADDR');

    foreach ($aa as $key) {
        if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true) {
            foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip) {
                if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false) {
                    return $ip;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
#endfunc

echo get_ip_address();
```

Comment: function get_ip_address()  
{
  $aa = array
  (
    'HTTP_CLIENT_IP', 
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR', 
    'HTTP_X_FORWARDED', 
    'HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP', 
    'HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR', 
    'HTTP_FORWARDED', 
//    'HTTP_HOST',
   'REMOTE_ADDR'

  );
  foreach ( $aa as $key)  
  {
    if (array_key_exists($key, $_SERVER) === true)  
    {
      foreach (explode(',', $_SERVER[$key]) as $ip)  
      {
        if (filter_var($ip, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP) !== false)  
        {
           return $ip;           
        } 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}#endfunc
echo get_ip_address();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's the purpose of proxies. You cannot reliably obtain the IP address of your user and, even if you could, do you mean their WAN address? Or one of any number of LAN addresses? It's an intractible problem in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function GetClientIP()
{
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))
    //check ip from share internet
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))
    //to check ip is pass from proxy
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    }
    else
    {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }
    return $ip;
}
```

Comment: This is a nice function, but note that this will **not always** work. Proxies with harmful intends won't share such information for instance

Comment: Can you elaborate on "harmful intends"? And why would they not show that information?

Comment: Well if a 'hacker' hosts their own proxy server they can send whatever headers they want, so they will simply not send those headers to you.